# Can you "Stack" resource packs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, I know that resource packs are fully customisable, if you know what you're doing (as I've done it a bit myself), but since resource packs aren't limited to textures anymore, can you "stack" different resource packs?

For example, if k have one pack that applies textures, and had some custom sounds, can I apply a separate resource pack that only has updated villager sounds, and nothing else?

Comment: If you couldn't, the ability to activate multiple at once would be a pretty useless feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

When loading a resource pack, it is added to the list of active packs, instead of replacing anything. The list of active packs is displayed on the right half of the resource pack screen.

The game will look for assets in the uppermost pack first, so in your scenario you should ensure the villager sounds pack is at the top if other packs also provide the same files.

The order of packs can be changed by using the up and down arrows that appear when hovering over a loaded pack.